# Fixed navbar separates from top of browser on Chrome for iPhone

Tags: html, css, iphone, google-chrome

I have a website with a bootstrap fixed-to-top navigation bar ([example here](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/)), and noticed that, using Chrome on an iPhone, the navbar separates from the top of the screen by just a few pixels when scrolling quickly. This is shown in the following screenshot, from the bootstrap navbar example page:

[image: Fixed navbar separation]

This only happens on Chrome on an iPhone, and not on an iPad or any Mac/PC I've tested. It also happens on every website with a fixed navbar that I could find. The only thing I can think of is to extend the background color of the navbar up above the top of the browser so that, when the navbar is eventually pulled down, it doesn't fully separate from the screen. However, that still leaves the content of the navbar pulled down, and certainly seems like a dirty fix.

Has anyone else run into this issue, and is there any sort of known fix available?

Comment: Having noticed same issue here. I'm happy to put this as a Chrome bug as this only happens after you "pull down" to refresh. It gets really really confused after this - but this doesn't happen if you perform actions really really slowly.

Comment: tried adding `padding-top:20px; top: -20px;` - does not help either

Comment: And javascript is not able to address it either.  Tried to reposition to the top on all scroll events / window resize events, no luck.  Seems the viewport / widow gets distorted.  Also was able to reproduce on the occasional switch from portrait to landscape.

Comment: This is a chromium bug - none of the answers below address this issue. You can track bug status here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=609994

Answer (score 3):

I used a tricky way to cover this gap,
I set padding-top:100px to the nav, and then margin-top:-100px,
so when it happened again, the gap would be filled by the padding-top.

It works fine so far, and hope this can help you, too.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I've had the same problem, of having a space before the entire contents of `<body>` in chrome, the solution found in the end? I had a space `' '` symbol at the start of the doc, before the `<!DOCTYPE html>` tag, removing it fixed everything.

Could not believe it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution, but adding a white bar above the element will improve the situation by preventing the content from peaking through:

```
.fixed-header:after {
    content: '';
    position: fixed;
    top: -20px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fff; // whatever your nav background color is
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just ran into the same problem about a week ago. I was using Bootstrap and discovered this problem in Google Chrome on the iPhone. Try putting a `<div class="wrapper"></div>` around all of your content besides the fixed-to-top navbar. Once that's finished style your page with the following CSS:

```
body, html {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden !important;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: white;
  overflow-x: hidden !important;
  width: 100vw;
  display: block;
}

html {
  overflow-x: hidden !important;
  width: 100vw;
  display: block;
}

.wrapper {
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden !important;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.navbar {
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: indigo;
}
```

EDIT: Google has fixed this, so this is no longer a problem. Thank God!

Comment: The `position: absolute` that is in your answer behaves completely differently from the `position: fixed` that is desired. From what I can tell, there is no way to solve this problem other than the hack described in my post and another answer, while keeping the necessary fixed position.